# Revalidating cache in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, caching

Whenever I deploy new changes, it doesn't reflect on the user interface immediately until I clear the browser cache. It is a react front end and node back end

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add versioning to your resouces (js and css) like this `<script src = "filename.js?version = 1.0"></script>`. You can add anything after `?`, make sure it is unique each time you update your code. Browsers will cache files based on full path.

Or more common approach, you will need to use js bundler like webpack so it can generate unique hashes to your scripts and embed them in your html.

Comment: Could you explain more on both approaches?

Comment: @DaviesTonui what exactly you want to be explained? How it works? Or how to implement it in your project?

Comment: @DaviesTonui in first approach you manually resolve version, it can be version from package or random number every time. So in the place where you resolve you html page in your node.js app you will need to set something to your js and css. I do not know the exact template engine you using, but it could be something like `<script src = "filename.js?v={Date.now()}"></script>` for all scripts and css. This will force to reload fresh resources every time you refresh the page.

Comment: @DaviesTonui second approach will need more skills to understand and also more entelligent to the cache, but basically there is js bundler https://webpack.js.org/ that will handle resources injection for you. And with little configuration it will add hash to the files automatically (hash will be calculated on file content, so it will be different every time you change something) like `entry.b888b78916b40e0f2523.js`

Comment: Thanks. I will try both but I have tried to implement but it kinda confusing https://dev.to/ammartinwala52/clear-cache-on-build-for-react-apps-1k8j